# "Cannot find User without an ID" error after logging in using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have started building a simple rails app and have used Devise for authentication. I have created a Dashboard page for the users after they login, it's using a users_contoller added below:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I have renamed this user#show to dashboard in routes:

```
match '/dashboard', to: 'user#show'
```

I have created a if else statement in the User show html page to see if this works, shown below:

```
<% if @user.lists.any? %>
    Cool you have lists
<% else %>
    OK No Lists
    <%= @user[:id] %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately this just renders an error when trying to load the page in a browser

```
 Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Im not sure if this is simply a Devise setting or something more fundamental and apologies in advance if this is avery noob question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user is autenticated using devise the current autenticated user is "stored" in a helper called "current_user".

A quick fix for your problem should be changing the code in your "UserController" to something like this (at the same time mantaning the rest funcionality):

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def show
        @user = params[:id].blank? ? current_user : User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route:
`match '/dashboard', to: 'user#show'` doesn't include the `id` parameter, you need to do as @Immendes suggested and use the `current_user` helper otherwise change your route to:
`match '/dashboard/:id', to: 'user#show'` and send the id